# application not working properly in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Whenever I try to run my android application, it gets crashed automatically. But when I checked this application in another system it is working awesomely. I have also checked it in different emualator.I have even tried downlaoding a fersh package and using it.But this problem is occuring again.

Can you people please tell me what's wrong with my system?

Here is the Log cat details

[image]

Anyhelp is appreciated :)

Comment: Share your code, what you are working with depends

Comment: Can u show us some code as well?

Comment: can you please  put up your layout files.

Comment: as i have told it is working properly without any error in another system

Comment: well at least you could show the whole stacktrace. my guess is a the error is printed more below in the trace.

Comment: @rupinder18 put your xml file.. error is in there.